# Avoid Okta dependency on application properties

Tags: java, spring-security-oauth2, okta

My application allows customers to perform OKTA SSO. Whenever a new customer signs in the contract, I have to add bunch of properties in application properties file and deploy the code again on the server. Example of the properties are as follows -

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta-customer1.client-id=
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta-customer1.client-secret=
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta-customer1.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta-customer1.scope=
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta-customer1.redirect-uri={baseUrl}/{action}/oauth2/code/{registrationId}

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.okta-customer1.authorization-uri=
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.okta-customer1.token-uri=
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.okta-customer1.user-info-uri=
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.okta-customer1.user-name-attribute=sub
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.okta-customer1.jwk-set-uri=
```

Is there a better way to do this? Can we avoid update to application.properties everytime and somehow load the properties from DB or any other better alternative?

My application is a spring boot application and I am using oauth2 protocol.

Comment: If you use the [Okta Spring Boot starter](https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot), you can get your properties down to one: `okta.oauth2.issuer`. You can also set this as an environment variable. For example `OKTA_OAUTH2_ISSUER=value ./mvnw spring-boot:run`

Comment: Hi Matt, how can we configure more than one issuer?

Comment: Matt, also is it possible to set this value from db? so that the dependency on the properties file will be removed?

Comment: You probably could set the value from the DB. You'd have to configure Spring Boot to do this somehow. Here its externalized configuration documentation. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config